# Load different mesh on each frame of an animation

Tags: python, animation, mesh, scripting, node-editor

I have several hundred meshes which describe a constantly changing surface like waves in the ocean. The amount of data in the meshes is so large, it will not fit in a single blender file.

I could manually load the mesh, render, and repeat, but that is not practical,

How can an animation be setup to replace a mesh on each frame? Ideally, the mesh in an object is replaced at each frame so materials and other settings are kept.

Are there any alternatives to scripting?

Comment: In a "single blender model": Do you mean a single Blender file or a single Blender mesh object?

Comment: @Leander, thanks for the comment. The question was updated to clarify.

Comment: Alembic cache behaves like series of meshes, Blender also supports series of such cache-files. Maybe it will help

Comment: You can make a script that loads you the mesh and assigns it to your object and append the script to frame change app handlers. You also probably want to remove the old meshes data there. Then you can just render the animation as usual. https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.app.handlers.html

Comment: I would definitely look into exporting as Alembic files.

Comment: I'm investigating this add-on - https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ